# Структура данных для быстрой выборки диапазона значений

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть массив объектов, представляющих собой ключ и значение. производится добавление и поиск по массиву объектов.

Как осуществить быстрый поиск объектов по диапазону ключей (например если ключ - дата, то поиск по диапазону дат соответственно)?

Какую структуру данных лучше использовать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Из подходящих структур данных - любое сбалансированное дерево - например, [Red/Black](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) или [AVL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree).

Из готовых структур в C# ближе всего, наверное, [`SortedSet<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070(v=vs.110).aspx) - в нем есть поиск по диапазону, но нет родной поддержки хранения пар ключ-значение.

`SortedDictionary<K, V>` наоборот, поддерживает хранение пар, но не поддерживает поиск по диапазону.

Так что проще всего будет использовать `SortedSet`, объявив свой контейнер для пар, который будет переопределять сравнение и equality:

```
class KeyValueHolder<TKey, TValue> : IComparable<KeyValueHolder<TKey, TValue>>
    where TKey : IComparable<TKey>
{
    public KeyValueHolder(TKey key, TValue value = default(TValue))
    {
        this.Key = key;
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public TKey Key { get; private set; }
    public TValue Value { get; private set; }

    public int CompareTo(KeyValueHolder<TKey, TValue> other)
    {
        return this.Key.CompareTo(other.Key);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var other = obj as KeyValueHolder<TKey, TValue>;
        return other != null && other.Key.Equals(this.Key);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

и использовать его как:

```
var set = new SortedSet<KeyValueHolder<DateTime, int>>();

for (int i = -5; i < 5; i++)
{
    set.Add(new KeyValueHolder<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(i), i));
}

// найдет пары от -2 до 2
set.GetViewBetween(
    new KeyValueHolder<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2.5)),
    new KeyValueHolder<DateTime, int>(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2.5))
    ).ToList().ForEach((kv) => Console.WriteLine(kv.Value));
```

Обернуть это в свой класс-контейнер и добавить синтаксический сахар по вкусу.

Вместо `KeyValueHolder` можно использовать стандартный `KeyValuePair<K, V>` передав set-у в конструктор свой `IComparer<KeyValuePair<K, V>>` для сравнения по ключу.

Внутри у `SortedSet` - [Red-Black Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). Вставка нового элемента за O(log n), поиск одного элемента или диапазона - тоже за O(log n). Перебор диапазона - за линейное время.

Из потенциальных проблем - в методе поиска диапазона [есть сомнительный код, который заставляет работать его линейное время от количества найденных элементов](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850975/why-sortedsett-getviewbetween-isnt-olog-n) - так что если регулярно находятся большие диапазоны - лучше написать свою реализацию.

У решений на основе `SortedDictionary<K, V>` сложность будет тоже O(log n)/O(log n).

---

Если новые данные добавляются только в конец - то можно попробовать вариант с `SortedList<TKey, TValue>`.[Сложность добавления при записи в случайном порядке O(N)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132330(v=vs.110).aspx) делает его применение сомнительным. Но если данные добавляются в конец, то сложность падает до O(log n).

Поиск диапазона сводится к поиску двух индексов. Если граничные значения точно есть в списке - то через два вызова `.IndexOfKey`. Если нет - то бинарным поиском. Оба варианта - O(log n).

По найденным индексам можно достать значения из `.Values` - это `IList<TValue>`. Обращение по индесу в `.Values` - O(1). Сам по себе вызов `.Values` - тоже O(1).

Answer (score 4):

Думаю, вам нужен упорядоченный словарь.

Это [`map<K, V>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) в C++ или [`SortedDictionary<K, V>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) в .NET.

Например, в `std::map` элементы в данном диапазоне лежат в последовательном куске, который начинается с итератора [`map.lower_bound(kmin)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound) и заканчивается итератором [`map.upper_bound(kmax)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound). Нахождение обоих итераторов логарифмическое.

Для `SortedDictionary<K, V>` у вас нету функций наподобие `Lower`/`UpperBound`, но их легко заимплементировать самому при помощи бинарного поиска по `SortedDictionary<K, V>.Keys` (который выдаёт *отсортированный* список ключей).

---

Как оказалось, `SortedDictionary<K, V>.Keys` не имплементирует `IList<K>`, и значит, в нём нельзя использовать двоичный поиск. Это явный недостаток BCL. В таком случае воспользуйтесь `SortedSet` с кастомным компаратором.